# Processing: webcam save and playback bug

Tags: arrays, image, arraylist, processing, webcam

I should be beyond this, but I can't get to the bottom of this error. I'm trying to write a sketch that records the feed of my Mac camera and stores each recording "session" into a PImage array, then adds that to a list of sessions (a PImage[] ArrayList). I'm using a 'Replay' class to access the images stored in memory to and replay them at a random position. The code below should be ready to be copied straight into the IDE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have no idea why the replay objects are always displaying the live image. Thanks!

```
import processing.video.*;
Capture cam;

ArrayList<PImage[]> allImages;
ArrayList<PImage> currentImages;
ArrayList<Replay> replays;

boolean recording = false;
boolean finishedSaving = true;
int currentIndex = 0;

void setup() {
  size(1056, 704, P2D);
  frameRate(30);

  allImages = new ArrayList<PImage[]>();
  currentImages = new ArrayList<PImage>();
  replays = new ArrayList<Replay>();

  String[] cams = Capture.list();
  if (cams.length == 0) {
    println("No cams!");
    exit();
  } else {
    cam = new Capture(this, 1056, 704, cams[0], 30);
    cam.start();
  }

}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  if (cam.available() == true) {
    cam.read();
  }


  for (Replay r : replays) {
    r.display();
  }

  if (recording) {
    currentImages.add(cam);
    noFill();
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    strokeWeight(5);
    rect(0, 0, cam.width/3, cam.height/3);
  } else {
    saveToArray();
  }

  image(cam, 0, 0, cam.width/3, cam.height/3);

}

void saveToArray() {
  if (!finishedSaving) {
    PImage[] tempImages = currentImages.toArray(new PImage[currentImages.size()]);
    allImages.add(tempImages);
    currentImages.clear();
    println("Finished saving to allImages array");
    println("allImages array size now = " + allImages.size());

    replays.add(new Replay(currentIndex));
    println("Added new Replay (index: " + currentIndex + ")");
    currentIndex++;
    finishedSaving = true;
    println();
  }

}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
    recording = !recording;
    println("Recording: " + recording);
    finishedSaving = false;
  }
}

class Replay {

  PVector position;
  float w, h;
  PImage[] images;
  int count;

 Replay(int allImagesIndex) {
   w = cam.width/3;
   h = cam.height/3;
   position = new PVector(random(width-w), random(height-h));
   count = 1;
   images = allImages.get(allImagesIndex);
 }

 void display() {
   image(images[count], position.x, position.y, w, h);
   count++;
   if (count > images.length-1) count = 1;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was due to the camera feed always being assignment to each individual image. To get a "copy" of the "current" video stream frame, I just added .get() to the feed so it fetches the pixels and stores them in a PImage variable.

```
currentImages.add(cam.get());
```